# NPE on connection with postgres and slick

Tags: postgresql, playframework, slick, hikaricp

I cannot connect my postgres database (AWS RDS) and I have no idea on how to fix this:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1001ms of waiting for a connection.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12)
        at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter$DatabaseAdapter.getConnection(DBApiAdapter.scala:57)
        at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter$DatabaseAdapter.getConnection(DBApiAdapter.scala:60)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.databaseEvolutions(EvolutionsApi.scala:124)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:102)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:117)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:446)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My connection seems right:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgres://<url>"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = ""
slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery = "select 1"
```

I try to use this project: https://github.com/vahana-team/play-slick-postgres

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you give a version of Hikari you're using and also put a breakpoint on `BaseHikariPool.java:446` to find out which value is null?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a configuration issue: the url should not be "jdbc:postgres://" but  "jdbc:postgresql://" !

Comment: That shouldn't give a NPE, you should get a nicer error message. You might want to file a bug report with either Slick or HikariCP if you can debug which one is causing the issue.